# Обновление Maven

Tags: netbeans, maven

Как обновить Maven для NetBeans 8.0.2?

Comment: Что вы пробовали и в чем проблема?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 2):

1. Скачать новую версию [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)
2. Разархивировать скачанный архив

   Замените дефисы в названии папки с разархивированным Maven на нижние подчеркивания,
   например:
   apache-maven-3.3.3  на   apache_maven_3.3.3

   Из-за дефисов в названии папки иногда могут возникать проблемы с путями.
3. Настроить  Maven ([инструкция 1](http://www.apache-maven.ru/install.html))

   На компьютере должна быть обязательно установлена виртуальная машина java.
4. **Запустить Netbeans** и перейти в настройки
   **Tools > Options > Java** |
   **вкладка Maven**

и  указать домашнюю директорию Maven (папку в которую был распакован архив)

[image: выбор домашней папки мавен]

5. нажать **ОК**